# Python asyncio wait and notify

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying to do something similar like C# ManualResetEvent but in Python.

I have attempted to do it in python but doesn't seem to work.

```
import asyncio

cond = asyncio.Condition()

async def main():
    some_method()

    cond.notify()

async def some_method():
    print("Starting...")
    
    await cond.acquire()
    await cond.wait()
    cond.release()
    
    print("Finshed...")

main()
```

I want the some_method to start then wait until signaled to start again.

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't seem to work" means? What does your program do or not do that surprises you?

Comment: Your title suggests you are using `threading`, but you're really asking about interrupting and continuing an async routine, which is not the same - `asyncio` uses a single-threaded event loop.

Comment: P.S., I don't know Python's `asyncio`. I tried running your program as-is, and got error messages. I read some documentation, and tried improving the program, but I got other error messages. Not really interested in pressing on, but if your problem is an error message that you don't understand, then you should put the exact text of the error message into your question, and maybe somebody who knows more than I can tell you how to avoid it.

Comment: This code can't possibly run; you can't simply call a coroutine (like `main`) from synchronous code. It sounds like you may want to walk through some `asyncio` tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not complete, first of all you need to use [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) to bootstrap the event loop - this is why your code is not running at all.

Secondly, `some_method()` never actually starts. You need to asynchronously start `some_method()` using [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task). When you call an "`async def` function" (the more correct term is coroutinefunction) it returns a coroutine object, this object needs to be driven by the event loop either by you `await`ing it or using the before-mentioned function.

Your code should look more like this:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    cond = asyncio.Condition()

    t = asyncio.create_task(some_method(cond))

    # The event loop hasn't had any time to start the task
    # until you await again. Sleeping for 0 seconds will let
    # the event loop start the task before continuing.
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    cond.notify()

    # You should never really "fire and forget" tasks,
    # the same way you never do with threading. Wait for
    # it to complete before returning:
    await t

async def some_method(cond):
    print("Starting...")
    
    await cond.acquire()
    await cond.wait()
    cond.release()
    
    print("Finshed...")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You have to acquire() cond in main as well, otherwise you get "RuntimeError: cannot notify on un-acquired lock"